# Как приостановить работу android приложения в фоном режиме?

Tags: java, android, c++, activity, android-manifest

Есть android-приложение. При запуске на устройстве и переходе в фоновый режим это приложение все еще остается активным.
 И собственно вопрос: как приостановить работу этого приложения в фоновом режиме?
 У меня есть предположения, что надо что-то дописать в AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: остается активным - оно  бегает в сеть, проявляет активность, или просто Вы увидели, что оно висит в списке задач и так решили?

Comment: У меня в игре змейка продолжает бежать пока в стенку не врежется, то есть приложение остаётся активным) И звуки работают, когда я нахожусь в главном окне андроид.

Comment: в активности в onPause нужно все останавливать

Comment: не останавливать,а паузить. А в OnResume - запускать. Просто смотрите на это https://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity